# GitHub Code highlighting for React file with js extension

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github

If you create a React file but save it with `.js` extension, then GitHub code highlighting breaks when it reaches a single quote in text. Saving the same file in `.jsx` works fine.

See example on [this repo](https://github.com/ktalebian/react-highlighting-problem). Both file `correct-highlighting.jsx` and `incorrect-highlighting.js` have the same content. As you can, the `.js` has wrong syntax highlighting.

Is there anyway to fix this, while still using `.jx` extension?

Comment: I've always been curious as to why someone would want to have the `.js` extension for a file that is `JSX` syntax, is there a benefit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A somewhat cumbersome solution based on the [Linguist readme](https://github.com/github/linguist#using-emacs-or-vim-modelines) is to add a vim or emacs modeline to the file. Appears you can add it within a JS comment to keep your source valid while maintaining correct syntax formatting on GH.

https://gist.github.com/ryanjduffy/50ba7c8d8adcbe1615cb016bf799cc69

```
// vim: syntax=JSX
import React from 'react';

export default class MyClass extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <a href="google.com">Let's head to google.com</a>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you can force the syntax of a file on github.  https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/31654/force-github-syntax-highlighting-language-on-source-files

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the reason you see incorrect JSX highlighting when the file has the .js extension is really because .jsx is incorrect JavaScript Syntax, so by virtue of GitHub having an accurate syntax highlighter and language detection gem ([Linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist)) JSX syntax doesn't get highlighted correctly.

This problem exists for .js extension purists as Text Editors *can* change which types of files to treat as certain types of extensions. I know a few syntax highlighter plugins include .js files as a valid extension to treat as .jsx, but that can also be removed, because if you were to run the file on it's own without React, it obviously wouldn't work.

You could be proactive however and file (or contribute to) an issue in [Linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist), and ask github to expand JSX syntax highlighting to files with a .js extension.